# Text spilling over out of UILabel container in TableView cell using .lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle

Tags: ios, swift, string

I've got a UILabel in my cell and it gets filled from text from my model that is being shortened with

```
text.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
```

If the text is longer than what will fit in my UILabel, the text continues to show until it's off the side of my cell.

[image]

As you can see the K is being cut off by the right end of the cell and there are like 5 more characters that follow in the string.

What I would like to happen is if the string was "123456789101112" for the string to be shortened enough to fit within my UILabel and not spill out of the right side of the label and look something like "1234...1112".

Edit: Tried adding some constraints, still having the same issue.

[image]

What I'm trying to say with those constraints are to have a constant width and to pin it to the sides so there's no chance for overflow , but even with those it's having the same issue.

I have a collection view and added the same constraints to that cell and it worked perfectly. Should there be something different needing to be done just because it's a tableview cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all probability the label *itself* is spilling off the right of the screen. You need to give it *constraints* so that the whole label stays on the screen no matter what size the screen is.

In this example, the label contains your "123456789101112" string:

[image]

Comment: Added an edit. I've got the same label being shown in a collection view and a table view cell. Adding constraints worked for the collection view, and adding the same sort of constraints in the tableview didn't work. Should I need to do anything different for a tableview?

Comment: Nevermind, just reset all of my constraints from scratch and it worked. Something must have been funky that I wasn't seeing. Thanks matt!